# Batch create multiple sub folders into other sub folders

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a folder that has sub folders labeled 0001-0999 in it. Within that, there are three sub folders, A, B, C. What I would like to do is batch create a bunch of folders to go into sub folder A. Currently, I can only get this to work by calling out the specific folder number (0001).

What I'm working with now:

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\Folders\0001\A) 
DO mkdir "%A\a" & mkdir "%A\b" & mkdir "%A\c" & mkdir "%A\d" & mkdir "%A\e"
```

Is there a way to replace the 0001 with something so all folders are selected or am I stuck doing this 999 times?

Comment: Hint. Nested `for` loops. Read [For - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Comment: `mkdir` can create all subfolders in one go. I.e. `mkdir a\b\c\d\e\f\g`

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple way to do this that you can build on if needed:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Folders"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%A in (%dir%\*) do (
    set "sub=%%A\A"
    cd !sub!
    md a b c d e 2>nul
)
```

Everything is accomplished in one loop. The first thing I did was set a variable (`dir`) for your directory, then `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is needed to be able to assign and use your variables within the loop. For the loop itself: it looks at all subfolders in your directory (`/d in %dir%\*`) and assigns each subfolder to a parameter (`%%A`). The parameter is used to set a new variable (`!sub!`) where we can specify the subfolder (`\A`) in which you'd like to make your new folders (a, b, c, d, and e from your code). The next thing we do is change the directory (`cd`) so we don't have to specify our subfolder for every folder we're creating with the make directory (`md`) command. Lastly, `md a b c d e 2>nul` will make each of those folders in our directory and sends the error messages to `nul` (it will error if the subfolder already exists). That's it! Hopefully this helped you or whoever stumbles upon this question.